# Resources for advanced bpy users?

Tags: python

I arrived at a point where I encountered/overviewed the majority of what `bpy` has to offer, and most resources we can find online are aimed at beginners are.

So I'm wondering what the best websites, books, or threads we can read to perfect/deepen our knowledge on various subjects related to blender python are?

Comment: Too less advanced tutorial for blender api. The solution is read the source code or ask question here.

Comment: i've already been reading a lot of bpy source code (mainly the class structure generated from `bpy_struct` ect) and i believe a lot is not meant for us to be used directly, any modules you found particularly interesting to discover?

Comment: Not yet, they are all boring.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious answer would probably be [Blender Python API Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html) . It is probably one of the best resources for learning about Blender Python API. As well as countless add-ons for Blender that come with Blender or that you can download online. You can just read the source code of them and study how they are made. I cannot imagine any better resources to be honest since those are the real deal, real world stuff and no tutorial can give you better examples.